# Weird PHP echo behaviour when setting echo'ing into a html value field

Tags: php, html, sql-server

lets jump straight into the issue.

I have a DB entry which is a string in the column name1 and looks f.e. like this: COMPANYNAME DIVADAY

The main attribute of this string is that it's mostly a string combined of two or more words separated with a comma.

Now when I print these entries out like this:

```
echo ("<td><input id=\"firmenname1\" type=\"text\" value=".$row['firmenname1']." /></td>");
```

now I check the result in the browser and experience some funny output. The value of the input is set to the **first** word in the string. So the value in this example looks like **COMPANYNAME**.
When I inspect the element to check whether it got lost in space or so I see this :

```
<input type="text" value="COMPANYNAME" DIVADAY />
```

Somehow the value gets attribute gets closed right after or before every comma and therefore the whole name can't be seen by the user.

Uppon inspecting the strings in my DB i couldn't really see if there are any hidden characters which lead to that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try echo in this way

```
echo "<td><input id='firmenname1'  type='text' value=".$row['firmenname1']." /></td>";
```

Comment: oh god... how could I miss that. Thanks :9

Answer (score 1):

Quotes are missing for value attribute.

```
echo ("<td><input id=\"firmenname1\" type=\"text\" value=\"{$row['firmenname1']}\" /></td>");
```

You can also try adding `addslashes` to the value.

```
$firmenname1 = addslashes($row['firmenname1'])
echo ("<td><input id=\"firmenname1\" type=\"text\" value=\"{$firmenname1}\" /></td>");
```

Comment: oh god... how could I miss that. Thanks :9

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put quotes around type database output:
you should write:

```
echo ("<td><input id=\"firmenname1\" type=\"text\" value=\"".$row['firmenname1']."\" /></td>");
```

In the way it is written, the html code became:

and the browsers parses COMPANYNAME as the value and divaday as a separate attribute of the input element. If you put the additioal quotes around "COMPANYNAME DIVADAY" you should see the correct result.

Comment: oh god... how could I miss that. Thanks :9

Answer (score 1):

Try adding quotes around the value attribute:

```php
echo ("<td><input id=\"firmenname1\" type=\"text\" value=\"".$row['firmenname1']."\" /></td>");
```

Comment: oh god... how could I miss that. Thanks :9

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion I normally convert array items I'm going to use into variables, i.e. $firmenname1 = $row['firmenname1']; That way you can clean up and format the data before use. The added bonus is you don't have to worry about correct quotes and backslashes